# So I heard/ I heard so

Tags: sentence-construction, parts-of-speech, so

> A: The Council has given planning permission for another shopping
>   centre in the city.
>
> B: ***So I read in the paper***.

Can I use "***I read so in the paper***" or "***I read in the paper so***" in the place of the marked phrase above ?

Comment: The second alternative should be *I read in the paper **it was** so*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Can I use "so I heard or I heard so" in the place of the marked phrase?

Comment: Aside from *read* and *heard* having different literal meanings, I see no reason why you couldn't exchange them.